# By any scientific/pseudo-scientific means could plasma be used to increase the lifespans of living creatures?

Tags: science-based, biology, physics, chemistry

In my semi-realistic science fantasy RPG, I want there to be a newly discovered chemical element that is perfect at generating plasma for use in various futuristic weapons and to increase the lifespans of creatures that remain in close proximity to it for extended lengths of time.

I'm not too smart when it comes to chemistry, or even science in general lol. Are there any discovered scientific methods/theories for methods on increasing lifespans by use of plasma?

EDIT: And by plasma, I'm referring to the fourth state of matter, not the component of blood.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, by "plasma" you mean [the high-energy state of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)), not [the component of blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_plasma)?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the fourth state of matter.

Comment: Well fire is plasma and cooking probably did more to increase the human lifespan than any discovery prior to antibiotics. Its not as if the use of plasma is new

Comment: A new element other than the currently known 118?

Comment: Do you mean "apply plasma in some way to a living creature and get a result," or do you mean "plasma does X which indirectly increases a creature's lifespan?"

Comment: @ltmauve The former

Comment: are you aware that your question is akin to 'are there life prolonging effects of solids' ? Solid Pb will kill you in bulletform, solid C will save you from poisoning in form of active coal, or kill you in form of blacklung. we know nothing about that new element of yours ...

Comment: If [tag:physics] isn't appropriate, please remove it.  It felt right to me.  I also added [tag:biology]

Answer (score 7):

This:

[image: Imsect killing lamp]

It attracts mosquitoes, which then die when they touch the electric grid. This gives you longevity by protecting you from insect-borne diseases such as malaria, dengue and zika.

And, since it's a good old, regular, unsophisticated, everyday down-to-earth fluorescent lamp, it works by getting a plasma (usually argon or mercury) to glow inside it.

Comment: @AlexP once again, thanks for helping me get things right :)

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo-science is available?

Then, do the sci-fi variant of [Energy Beings](https://tvtropes.org/Main/EnergyBeings) trope... Something like,

Destructively scan people's brains into intelligent blobs of plasma, where information is stored as the electromagnetic energy values or something of the plasma,  that interact with the world through some technologies.

That makes them sorta more immortal, since they're not subject to organic decay and stuff?

Or, possibly find a way for some sort of human-computer-plasma interface, so that there isn't

Comment: How would that work though? I know that’s an oxymoron of a question, but pseudo science is basically just an idea isn’t it?